# Choose content randomly in Go templates

Tags: templates, go

I would like to choose a part of the generated document randomly based on the given weights, something like this pseudo-code:

```
{{prob 50}}
    This will appear with probability 50%.
{{prob 30}}
    This will appear with probability 30%.
{{prob 20}}
     You got the idea.
{{endprob}}
```

The best things that has come to my mind so far is:

```
{{choose . "template1" 50 "template2" 30 "template3" 20}}
```

where `choose` is my function that belongs to `FuncMap`. The current template is passed to itself as e.g. `.T` and `templateN` are the associated templates. The function would choose the template, look it up in `.T` and render with `.`. Another similar option would be to pass `templateN` as part of `.` directly.

I wonder if there's a more elegant / less hackish way? I guess, it's not possible to create custom actions in `text/template`, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard template packages do not support custom actions.

You can get close to your proposed `{{prob}}/{{endprob}}` action using a function map and the built-in `{{if}}` action.

Convert the weights to non-overlapping ranges in [0.0,1.0). Use a random number in [0.0,1.0) to select an alternative using an if action in the template.

```
var t = template.Must(template.New("").
    Funcs(template.FuncMap{"rand": rand.Float64}).
    Parse(`
{{$r := rand}}
{{if le $r 0.5}}
    This will appear with probability 50%.
{{else if le $r 0.8}}
    This will appear with probability 30%.
{{else}}
     You got the idea.
{{end}}`))
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/c_4SryGkL8)</kbd>

Here's an alternative that allows you to specify weights in the template instead of ranges:

```
type randPicker struct {
    n float64 // random number in  [0.0,1.0)
    t float64 // total of weights so far
}

func (rp *randPicker) Weight(w float64) bool {
    rp.t += w
    return rp.t <= rp.n
}

func newRandPicker() *randPicker {
    return &randPicker{n: rand.Float64()}
}

var t = template.Must(template.New("").
    Funcs(template.FuncMap{"rp": newRandPicker}).
    Parse(`
{{$rp := rp}}
{{if rp.Weight 0.50}}
    This will appear with probability 50%.
{{else if rp.Weight 0.30}}
    This will appear with probability 30%.
{{else}}
    You got the idea
{{end}}`))
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oGbawWH4Xg)</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely an  option, just trying to make it a bit more user-friendly.